# File name search in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQl database and there i have a column named file name. In my web application user enters a text to search (more than one word) and I want to get the matching file names. I want not only the exact matching names. I want to get the file names which matches to the text approximately (Having more than three matching words).
Can anybody suggest a way to do this?

Comment: are your file names multiple words?

Comment: Split the search string at spaces (or comma if tag-like), include it in your SQL, which you not seem to have.

Comment: I suggest to try the SQL "in" Statement. Look here:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956048/sql-where-x-in-select-y-from

Comment: @SamDufel yes. File names may have multiple words

Comment: @Nadeeshaan you should post an example: a possible content of a few entries in the DB and an example input from the user, as well as the expected output of the program.

Comment: I think I can use the FULLTEXT search in MYSQL for this scenario. That provides many features to match a text to a text field in the database..

Comment: No, I doubt that the Fulltext search will be helpful here. For one, it considers everything shorter than four characters a “stop word” that does not get indexed, so file name extensions could be problematic form the start. And I’m not even sure it would consider something with a dot in it (`foo.bar`) two separate words.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';